# Dask read_parquet for nested parquet files

Tags: python, dask, parquet, pyarrow, dask-dataframe

I have a number of csv files (90+) that are too large for memory (~0.5gb each zipped) which all have same schema. I want to convert to parquet and then use dask for time series analysis.

Currently I read them into pandas, perfom a few type checks and business logic, and then use `ddf.to_parquet` to send to parquet. I want to partition by date and by a version number. Therefore the code looks like:

```py
import pandas as pd
import dask.dataframe as ddf
import pyarrow.dataset as ds

d = pd.DataFrame({'DATE':[202001, 202002, 202003, 202004, 202005]*20,'VERSION':[0,1]*50,'OTHER':[1]*100})
d_dask = ddf.from_pandas(d,npartitions=2)
ddf.to_parquet(d_dask, 'some/path/', engine = 'pyarrow', partition_on = ['DATE', 'VERSION'], \
write_metadata_file = True, schema='infer')
```

Now this works, and I end up with a folder structure which looks like:

'some/path/_metadata'

'some/path/_common_metadata'

'some/path/DATE=202001/VERSION=0/part.0.parquet'

.... and so on.

Now I would like to read it in and do basic operations out of memory. I get strange results on read.

```py
test_read = ddf.read_parquet('some/path/', engine='pyarrow',partitioning="hive")
test_read.groupby('DATE').sum()
```

I get the following:

```
[IN]: test_read.groupby('DATE').sum().compute()
```

```
[OUT]:

DATE     OTHER
202001    0
202002    0
202003    0
202004    0
202005    0
```

Now using the `pyarrow.datasets` API works just fine.

```py
test_read = ds.dataset('some/path/',format='parquet',partitioning="hive")
test_read.to_table().to_pandas().groupby('DATE').sum()
```

I get the following:

```
[OUT]:
        OTHER  VERSION
DATE                  
202001     20       10
202002     20       10
202003     20       10
202004     20       10
202005     20       10
```

Which is what I would expect.

Does anyone know what is going on here?

Versions:

```
[IN]:
print(dask.__version__,pyarrow.__version__)
[OUT]:
2.30.0 2.0.0
```

Comment: Does it work if you do `test_read.groupby('DATE')['OTHER'].sum().compute()` ?

Comment: I believe that dask's handling of pyarrow 2x is still incomplete, but coming soon.

Comment: Ah thanks @mdurant. I've tried downgrading to pyarrow-1.0.5 and with dask.2.3, but I 
get a long traceback "ValueError: buffer source array is read-only" when doing the out of memory groupby operation. I'm wondering if there is somewhere where I can find version matching recommendations. Like, if you have dask 2.3, use pyarrow > 1, <2 or something like that. Is there a version combination where the above example will work?